# Including FontAwesome icons with ACF checkbox output

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently using ACF checkbox for provisional items and decided to add FontAwesome icons to the output.
I firth tried to add the icons within the ACF values but nothing showed, this is my attempt (much longer) at generating this with icons.

My current code is

```
<?php
    $provisions = get_sub_field('activity_provisions');
    if ($provisions):
        ?>
        <h3>We provide</h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <?php if (in_array('Experienced guide', $provisions)): ?>
                    <li><i class='fas fa-link fa-4x'>&nbsp;</i> Experienced guide</li>
                <?php elseif (in_array('Shower facilities', $provisions)): ?>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-link fa-4x">&nbsp;</i> Shower facilities</li>
                <?php elseif (in_array('Locker or waterproof bag', $provisions)): ?>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-link fa-4x">&nbsp;</i> Locker or waterproof bag</li>
                <?php elseif (in_array('Experienced guide', $provisions)): ?>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-link fa-4x">&nbsp;</i> Life jackets</li>
                <?php elseif (in_array('Experienced guide', $provisions)): ?>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-link fa-4x">&nbsp;</i> Helmets</li>
                <?php elseif (in_array('Experienced guide', $provisions)): ?>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-link fa-4x">&nbsp;</i> Paddles</li>
                <?php elseif (in_array('Experienced guide', $provisions)): ?>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-link fa-4x">&nbsp;</i> Safety Insurance</li>
                <?php elseif (in_array('Experienced guide', $provisions)): ?>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-link fa-4x">&nbsp;</i> Meal</li>
                <?php elseif (in_array('Transport', $provisions)): ?>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-link fa-4x">&nbsp;</i> Transport</li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

$provisions output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Experienced guide 
    [1] => Shower facilities 
    [2] => Helmets 
    [3] => Safety Insurance 
    [4] => Meal 
    [5] => Transport 
 )
```

I'm able to print out the first value but no further, could anyone please suggest a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance! <3

Comment: You need to do a `foreach` loop on the `$provisions` array. The reason you are only getting the first value, is because you are using an `if` statement. So it essentially meets the first requirement (if this exists) then exits out of the statement.

Comment: if you do `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $provisions, TRUE ) . '</pre>';`  directly after `if( $provisions)`, what is the output you get? That's the only way we can really help you.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Experienced guide
    [1] => Shower facilities
    [2] => Helmets
    [3] => Safety Insurance
    [4] => Meal
    [5] => Transport
)

Comment: sorry it's messy, doesn't allow line breaks here! Thanks for your speedy reply BTW, super appreciated :)

Comment: I had a foreach loop on the previous setup but this needs to have different icons for each item, the above is just a sample - hadn't changed all the icons until i knew this was feasible..

Comment: You just need to put the `if` statements in the `foreach` loop. You need to loop over all the elements in the array and then check to see if there is a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'm describing in my comment about the `foreach` loop:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $provisions as $provision ) : ?>
         <!-- IF STATEMENTS HERE -->
         <?php if ( $provision === 'Experienced guide' ) : ?>
             <li><i class='fas fa-link fa-4x'>&nbsp;</i> Experienced guide</li>
         <?php elseif ( $provision === 'Shower facilities' ) : ?>
             <li><i class='fas fa-link fa-4x'>&nbsp;</i> Shower facilities</li>
         <!-- ADD MORE ELSEIFS HERE -->
         <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>            
</ul>
```

You just need to iterate over the array items to output what you need. I'm assuming the icon is tied to the value of the array (e.g. Experienced Guide has its own icon), so then you just need to update the font-awesome icon for each one.

Comment: Thanks disinfor! This is almost perfect, it prints the options except the first one. I assume this is the way IF and ELSEIF are structured? Do you have any advice for multiple selections here?

Comment: Oh, you mean `Experienced Guide`? If so, lowercase `guide`. You need to make sure the `$provision === 'your text here'` matches the value of the array exactly. I edited the answer to reflect your initial array. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by multiple selections.

Comment: You sir, are an absolute hero. Thank you for your amazing answer <3